# Why this strange execution time

Tags: python, time, time-complexity

I am using this sorting algorithm:

```
def merge(L,R):
    """Merge 2 sorted lists provided as input
    into a single sorted list
    """
    M = [] #Merged list, initially empty
    indL,indR = 0,0 #start indices
    nL,nR = len(L),len(R)

    #Add one element to M per iteration until an entire sublist
    #has been added
    for i in range(nL+nR):
        if L[indL]<R[indR]:
            M.append(L[indL])
            indL = indL + 1
            if indL>=nL:
                M.extend(R[indR:])
                break
        else:
            M.append(R[indR])
            indR = indR + 1
            if indR>=nR:
                M.extend(L[indL:])
                break
    return M

def func(L_all):

    if len(L_all)==1:
        return L_all[0] 
    else:
        L_all[-1] = merge(L_all[-2],L_all.pop())
        return func(L_all)
```

merge() is the classical merge algorithm in which, given two lists of sorted numbers, it merges them into a single sorted list, it has a linear complexity. An example of input is `L_all = [[1,3],[2,4],[6,7]]`, a list of N sorted lists. The algorithm applies merge to the last elements of the list until there is just one element in the list, which is sorted. I have evaluated the execution time for different N, using constant length for the lists inside the list and I have obtained an unexpected pattern. The algorithm has a linear complexity but the execution time is constant, as you can see in the graph [image]

What could be the explanation of the fact that the execution time does not depend on N?.

Comment: where is the code for merge? how can we know what its doing to be able to answer why it runs like that.

Comment: "What could be the explanation of the fact that the execution time does not depend on N?" -- the simplest explanation is that your benchmarking isn't adequate.

Comment: Try 50,000 items instead of 50.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, I have just edited it to add the merge() function

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, I have tried with N up to 150 but the result barely changes

Comment: @JohnColeman. I am using the %timeit method, do you have any advice to improve the benchmarking?

Comment: The problem is likely to be not *how* you benchmark so much as *what* you benchmark. 150 is still quite far from the suggested 50,000. `O(N)` is not always easily distinguished from `O(1)` for smallish `N`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try to execute it up to 1000. Do you think that the difference will be more appreciable if I execute it for N=10000:11000 rather than for N=1:1000?

Comment: @laklica Why are you so reluctant to try large numbers? Try 50,000, not 1000. Sure, 1000 should also show a difference but these numbers are **tiny**. Try large numbers. You are generating random input samples, right?

Comment: The indentation in your final function is off, please fix. All of that recursion and destructive updating of the list of lists rather than a straightforward iterative solution which builds up a new list seems unmotivated and also a partial explanation of what you are seeing (you are measuring a lot of overhead). Also, I suspect that it is Python's stack limit which is preventing you from being able to benchmark large examples.

Comment: Apart from that, your function fundamentally *does not work*. It doesn’t sort anything. Did you try it? What’s the expected output for e.g. `func([[3, 8, 1]])`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph. Actually the inputs are sorted lists, as I say in the post. I would like to avoid such large numbers since it %timeit executes like 10000 iterations per call, therefore I prefer to do simulations with smaller number to avoid waiting so long. Nevertheless, if I am not able to spot any increment in the execution time I will do the simulations with those numbers

Comment: @laklica in [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) `number=1000000` is an optional parameter which can be changed. You could do a larger number of calls with smaller settings of `number`.

Comment: @chepner OP's example `L` is `[[1,3],[2,4]`. The function `func` mutates such an `L` into a single sorted list. It is perhaps a weird thing to do, and not that useful for implementing merge sort, but doesn't lead to a type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your timing code, but the problem is likely to be that your `func` *mutates* the list `L_all` so that it becomes a list of length 1, containing a single sorted list. After the first call `func(L_all)` in `timeit`, all subsequent calls don't change `L_all` at all. Instead, they just instantly return `L_all[0]`. Rather than 100000 calls to `L_all` for each `N` in `timeit` , you are in effect just doing *one* real call for each `N`. Your timing code just shows that `return L_all[0]` is `O(1)`, which is hardly surprising.

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
import functools, random, timeit

def func(L_all):
    return functools.reduce(merge,L_all)

for n in range(1,10):
    L = [sorted([random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(5)]) for _ in range(n)]
    print(timeit.timeit("func(L)",globals=globals()))
```

Then even for these smallish `n` you see a clear dependence on `n`:

```
0.16632885999999997
1.711736347
3.5761923199999996
6.058960655
8.796722217
15.112843280999996
17.723825805000004
22.803739991999997
26.114925834000005
```